# how to use iptables to block the IP of device connected to openwrt router

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, openwrt

- I have two routers(A,B).the A connect to internet with IP:192.168.1.1
- The openwrt router B connect the lan of A by bridge with static IP:192.168.1.111.
- I am learning to use iptables to control the devices connected to B(wlan) .
- I use my phone to connect wifi of B,the phone's IP is IP:192.168.1.100.it can surf the internet normally.
- I want to block the phone's IP to make the phone can not connect to internet.

refer to http://bredsaal.dk/some-small-iptables-on-openwrt-tips

- iptables -A input_wan -s 192.168.1.100 --jump REJECT
- iptables -A forwarding_rule -d 192.168.1.100 --jump REJECT

but it do not work.the phone still connect to internet normally.
and I tried other chain(INPUT,OUTPUT,FORWARD).so many chains confused me.

- iptables -I OUTPUT -o br-lan -s 192.168.1.100 -j DROP

and  it do not work again.

I'm sure that the iptables have no problem.

```
root@OpenWrt:/etc# iptables -L|grep Chain
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
Chain forward (1 references)
Chain forwarding_lan (1 references)
Chain forwarding_rule (1 references)
Chain forwarding_wan (1 references)
Chain input (1 references)
Chain input_lan (1 references)
Chain input_rule (1 references)
Chain input_wan (1 references)
Chain output (1 references)

root@OpenWrt:/etc# ifconfig
br-lan    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0C:82:68:97:57:BA  
      inet addr:192.168.1.111  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::e82:68ff:fe97:57ba/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:14976 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:7656 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:2851980 (2.7 MiB)  TX bytes:1902785 (1.8 MiB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0C:82:68:97:57:BA  
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:58201 errors:0 dropped:11 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:45012 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:54591348 (52.0 MiB)  TX bytes:5711142 (5.4 MiB)
      Interrupt:4 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:312 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:312 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:39961 (39.0 KiB)  TX bytes:39961 (39.0 KiB)

mon.wlan0 Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 0C-82-68-97-57-BA-00-48-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:4900 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:32 
      RX bytes:1223807 (1.1 MiB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0C:82:68:97:57:BA  
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:37346 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:49662 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:32 
      RX bytes:3808021 (3.6 MiB)  TX bytes:54486310 (51.9 MiB)

    root@OpenWrt:/etc/config# cat network 

config 'interface' 'loopback'
    option 'ifname' 'lo'
    option 'proto' 'static'
    option 'ipaddr' '127.0.0.1'
    option 'netmask' '255.0.0.0'

config 'interface' 'lan'
    option 'ifname' 'eth0'
    option 'type' 'bridge'
    option 'proto' 'static'
    option 'ipaddr' '192.168.1.111'
    option 'netmask' '255.255.255.0'
    option 'gateway' '192.168.1.1'
    option dns 192.168.1.1
```

and  how to use iptables to control the network of wlan?

Thanks in advance and sorry for poor English.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you just have to swap the -d (destination ip) with -s (source ip)

```
iptables -A forwarding_rule -s 192.168.1.100 --jump REJECT
```

the input and output chains are only eligible for packets send to or sent out the router itself.